# Copy jenkins build file(WAR) to a set of servers

Tags: jenkins, ant, jenkins-plugins, maven-plugin, jenkins-pipeline

The jenkins+ANT job creates a build(war file) on the slave node. I need this war file to be copied over to a set of 5 servers.

I am confused on what would be a good way to do it
I am exploring several options

1. Using the post build task plugin to copy the war file (But it runs into issue over permission)
2. Another option is to add ansible plugin and have a playbook copy the files(Haven't tried it yet)
3. Using the SCP plugin to copy the file to remote host

Could anybody please explain a bit about how this could be achieved ,Are the options mentioned above fine? Is there a better way to do it?

I am very new to jenkins,any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The best option I've found so far is to use:

```
sshagent(['ID-of-credentials']) {
    sh `scp file.war server1`
    sh `scp file.war server2`
    sh `scp file.war server3`
    sh `scp file.war server4`
    sh `scp file.war server5`
}
```

It is most straightforward.